# crossing over to php oop

Tags: php, oop

so far the syntax is not the problem but my question is more about better understanding OOP

I am creating a class called "user" which should describe a user. typically such class would set user variables and retrieve them

would that class have a method for signingup a new user as well?
how about login?

if not ..how would I structure it?

should "signing up" be another class? in which case wouldn't the resulting object be a "user"

same goes for the a login class...

sorry for the novis question....just trying to wrap my head around OOP.

thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most PHP OOP applications would use a model-view-controller (MVC) approach to solve this, with your user class being the 'model' and a 'controller' class providing business logic that interacts with your user class, like 'signup' or 'login'. The 'view' part refers to the presentation code (a mix of PHP / HTML) that gets output to the browser.

A controller approach would look something like this:

```
class UserController {

    public function signup($userDetails) {
        // create a new user
        $user = new User();
        $user->name = $userDetails['name'];
        $user->username = $userDetails['username'];
        $user->password = $userDetails['password'];
        $user->save(); // Save to database, for example
    }

    public function login($username, $password) {
        // check the user exists and log them in
        $user = new User();

        // query database for a user with these credentials, for example
        if($id = $user->find($username, $password)) {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $id; // Save the ID to the session for future use
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

This is just a really basic example, but generally you don't want to mix your application logic (actions such as login or signup) with your domain logic (which should just concern managing your data).

A good article on MVC in PHP can be found here: http://oreilly.com/php/archive/mvc-intro.html

Comment: am I right to assume that these methods "save" & "find"  are in the same UserController class also?

Comment: Sorry, I should have made that more clear. In the example above, they exist on the user class. That doesn't necessarily have to be the case; you could say the above example is an 'Active Record' (google it) approach in which the class contains methods that interact with a database table. The reason they're better off on the User class than on the UserController is that you're likely to want to call them elsewhere in the application. If you look in to how MVC is handled in a framework like CakePHP or Symfony it should make sense.

Comment: No worries. As Oswald says in his answer, you'll probably find that as you're writing your code you'll notice that it belongs in a class in its own right, e.g. having a UserRegistration class that actually does the sign up. You would then utilise an instance of this class in the 'signup' controller method to keep your controller compact - the controller is responsible for deciding what needs to be done, and doesn't necessarily have to do it, it depends on how complicated your logic is.

Answer (score 4):

Classes do not necessarily represent an entity from your experience. Sometimes they represent a concept:

- Registering a user is actually the job of the user management. Consider a class that represents the user management.
- Logging in is the job of the authentication component. Consider a class that represents the authentication component.

Theses are just some examples and they probably do not tell you the reasons why it is often done that way. For that I suggest literature about object oriented programming. That literature should tell you about separation of concerns, lose coupling, open/close principle, programming against interfaces, how to transform requirements into classes.